# Get and set printer ACL in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I would like to grant the group "users" the permission of deleting one printer using powershell.

How can I get the local printer's ACL and include this new ACL to thoses?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use WMI (`gwmi win32_printer`). This requires mucking around with security descriptors and isn't very friendly, but fortunately there's some information in MSDN. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa393594 and http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff730951 .

Answer (score 7):

Using powershell 4 on my 2012 server I do something like following for deploying our printers.

I create a temporary printer called 'TEMP' in this example and use the Security Tab to define printer permissions I want to have on a particular users printer or set of printers then I get the security descriptor property and dump it into a text file, you can store it to a variable if you like vs. dumping out to a text file like I show here.

```
(Get-Printer 'TEMP' -Full).PermissionSDDL | Out-File 'C:\OregonOperation.txt'
```

Then I use something like this to pull my saved Security settings into a variable.
    $perms = Get-Content 'C:\OregonOperation.txt'

Then to push it to particular printer you can do the following

```
Set-Printer 'NEWPRINTER' -PermissionSDDL $perms
```

If you wanted to target a remote computer, you need to add the `-Computer` parameter.

```
Set-Printer 'NEWPRINTER' -PermissionSDDL $perms -Computer 'SOMEWORKSTATION'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unforunately, I am working on Windows7 and have not the Get-Printer and Set-Printer functions.

Comment: I think Jeroen posted your best bet then. There is also this thread as well that could be useful. http://serverfault.com/questions/86477/grant-manage-printers-permission-for-all-printers-on-xp-clients-via-gpo

Comment: Wonderful idea ssaviers!  This worked perfectly for what I needed today.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use to blanket apply permissions across all printer on a print server. 
Server 2012 powershell v4

Set up a printer permissions for use as a template, and load them permissions into a variable.

```
$printerperms = (Get-Printer -ComputerName Printsvr -Name admin-printer -Full).PermissionSDDL
```

Get all printers from the server you wish to apply the permissions to.

```
$allprinters = get-printer -ComputerName Printsvr -name * | select name -ExpandProperty name
```

Using a "foreach" command, you can apply the permissions from the template printer and apply said permissions to all using the command below.

```
foreach ($printer in $allprinters)
{Set-Printer $printer -PermissionSDDL $printerperms -ComputerName Printsvr}
```